# SendTo menu is missing in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, context-menu, send-to

### Issue Description

I'm using Windows 10.0.19041.450 x64

I have my frequently used destination shortcut files inside the SendTo folder at:

```
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

[image]

But I just noticed from few weeks ago that all the items in my SendTo menu are missing:

[image]

The SendTo items are missing both if I open the context menu for a file, or for a directory.

### Research

I don't remember doing anything wrong that could harm or affect the SendTo menu behavior. I don't have any 3rd party software that runs a service on background related or that interacts with the context-menu. I never installed a 3rd party SendTo menu replacement. I don't have any 3rd party software that registers a shell extension, except [Link Shell Extensions](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) which I installed it like 5 months ago in order to make easy and productive the creation of some Symbolic Links for many folders in my machine. But I uninstalled it and I don't see a way that this shell extension could affect the SendTo menu shell extension, so I don't think that it could be the cause of this problem.

And for what I have found researching on the Internet:

The registry value: `(Default)` located at registry key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\SendTo` it has this value: `{7BA4C740-9E81-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837}` as described in [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/send-to-option-missing-from-the-right-click-menu/69656833-f8dc-407f-b4df-a25081da8831).

Other articles that I saw they just talk about problems caused by the *Bluetooth* shortcut file. They suggest to remove that shortcut file, or to make a copy of the entire SendTo folder including the *Bluetooth* shortcut file to "restore the default state of the SendTo folder content" (I even seen and tried a zip fiel containing the default SendTo directory from a fresh Windows installation). I tried everything related about it. And I must say that I'm using Windows 10 for years with the *Bluetooth* shortcut file hidden (and read-only) like in the image above, and It never gave me a problem with the SendTo menu, so I don't think that shortcut file is causing my problem now.

Comment: The Send TO menu is there in a vanilla Windows 10 (and 11) system, that is no damage and no registry changes.   Try running DISM / SFC  .....   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: There can be *SendTo* folders for each user, `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` . Though having all shortcuts in the *Administrador* folder must have been annoying, is it feasible to recreate them in another user's folder? Or just put the *Send via Bluetooth* shortcut in one user's folder, and the other shortcuts in Administrador's?

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik "Administrador" is the hidden built-in administrator account. It is the only account / username that I use. There are no other user folders on my machine in 'C:\Users' (just "Administrador", "Default" and "Public"). It always worked fine like this.

Comment: @John I just tried it, didn't fixed the problem.

Comment: If that is the case , you need to try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media creation link

Comment: @John I appreciate your help but I humbly hope you understand that if I post this topic it is to try to find a solution that does not involve generalized methods such as using a Windows 10 Repair Install media or trying to return all system components to their original default state, because I can just reinstall Windows 10 and keeping all my current files, but I'd rather not go that far (because I will lose all my system and software configurations), which is why I'm posting this topic. Also, I am someone who likes to (try to)discover the exact causes of problems to apply a specific solution.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Does the fix for "Case 2" here work → [Send To Menu Empty or Shows Only “Bluetooth Device”](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-send-to-bluetooth-device-windows-10/)

Comment: @ElektroStudios: By working under the hidden administrator account you have disabled UAC and voided almost every protection that Windows provides against malware!

Comment: With Windows 10 and 11, the most effective step beyond DISM / SFC is normally Repair Install. Very common and less time consuming than hunt and peck.

Comment: So it is nearly 24 hours later (2 working days). Have you found the issue by hunting and pecking at it?

Comment: @w32sh The registry data on my machine for **SendTo** registry value was of type REG_EXPAND_SZ and pointed to the same directory but spelled shorter: "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo", anyways I replaced it for the value "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo" as described in **Case 2**, logged-off and the problem persists.

Comment: @harrymc That is true, of course, but that's because I'm just cautious enough not to need to use UAC or antivirus either. I'm someone with a brain who doesn't download dubious executables or go to strange websites or click on links in spam emails. And for insecure things I use a sandbox software or a virtual machine.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Pitting your brain against hackers is pure hubris. As an example : You surely use Google, where sometimes malicious ads slip through.

Comment: @John Sorry for the delay buddy, I have not yet found a solution by hunting and pecking, but that is what I would like to try to continue doing with the help of all of yours, trying to rule out the known causes of this problem until we can find the root of this specific problem.

Comment: @harrymc I don't mean to deviate from the main topic, but I would like to say that I use an adblocker and an anti-miner in the web-browser. That is essential, yes, and quarterly I do a full analysis of virus/malware on my machine (as a habit,although I never get infected with virus), and I frequently use autoruns,but what it means to have an antivirus running in the background all the time as I have said I am cautious enough not to need that. In any case,I understand that you make these warnings, I consider them well done and surely they are essential suggestions for many kind of users.Thanks.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: See if temporarily disabling the extra (3rd party) context menu handler shell extensions using Nirsoft [ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) helps. Buggy shell extensions can cause [weird issues](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-slow-right-click-crashes-shell-extensions/) in Windows.

Comment: @w32sh I ended up breaking my boot loader, unable to load the loader to select the O.S, maybe because I disabled a nVidia shell-thing handler described as "System" (not as "Context Menu" like others) and some Microsoft's built-in context menu handlers and shell-extensions like "Sharing" and "Previous version page" and more which appears safe to be temporally disabled just to test, but I broke it as I said. So I finally reinstalled Windows 10 to restore the SendTo menu. Thanks you all.